# Как заместить элемент в GWT?

Tags: gwt

Имеется форма, в которой есть DIV с ID="photos". Из GWT кода вызывается

```
RootPanel photoRootPanel = RootPanel.get("photos");
```

Далее создается image

```
Image userImage = new Image((String) "http://www.xxx.com/images/user_thumb_large.jpg");
```

Как можно заместить photoRootPanel на userImage?

Answer (score 1):

А вам обязательно замещать? Возьмите родителя RootPanel и удалите его из него, а потом добавьте userImage.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так (если я правильно понял вопрос):

```
RootPanel.get("photos").clear();
RootPanel.get("photos").add(userImage);
```